# Word table copy/drag formula like Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I am inserting formula into a Word table to get subtotals for rows and columns and a grand total. My problem is, I have got large number of rows and I don't want to enter the formula manually in each cell.
I cannot use `=SUM(LEFT)` because the subtotal does not have all the columns.

So, is there any way to drag the formula like we do in Excel (bottom right corner of selected cell)?

I cannot send the table to Excel and copy it back because it would ruin the formatting which took a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

Word doesn't have the sort of drag 'n copy functionality of Excel. However you can achieve the same thing by first copying (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) your formula. Then highlight all of the cells you want the formula to appear in and then paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>). You should find all cells have been populated with the formula field now.